# how do i split array by values using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Since i dont know how to formulate question, i'll just try to explain what needed to be done.
Program should take all values from table data and on submit button insert values of table data into input fields (each value into one input field) multyply by inserted number. 
I managed to take values from table data but dont know how to procced. 
Here is code i created for test. NOTE (pure javascript required)

```
<html>
<input type="text" class="class1" id="1"></br>
<input type="text" class="class1" id="2"></br>
<input type="text" class="class1" id="3"></br>
<input type="text" class="class1" id="4"></br>
<input type="text" class="class1" id="5"></br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="class1" id="1">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="class1" id="2">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="class1" id="3">30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="class1" id="4">40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="class1" id="5">50</td>
    </tr>
</table>
insert number<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="submit" id="submit">

<script>
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
    var vrednost = "";
    for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        vrednost += elements[i].textContent;
    }
    document.write(vrednost);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Relate both the elements using `data-id` and select the element using `querySelector` specifying `data-id` attribute value.

Always remember that **ID** attribute must not be duplicate in a webpage.

You can not blindly rely on the `position` of the `td` and `input` elements as they may not be in sync.

*The [**Array.from()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.*

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("td.class1"); //Select all `td` elements having class as `class1`
  var mul = document.getElementById('text').value; //get multiplication value
  Array.from(elements).forEach(function(elem) {
    document.querySelector("input.class1[data-id='" + elem.dataset.id + "']").value = (+elem.textContent * +mul);
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="class1" data-id="1">
</br>
<input type="text" class="class1" data-id="2">
</br>
<input type="text" class="class1" data-id="3">
</br>
<input type="text" class="class1" data-id="4">
</br>
<input type="text" class="class1" data-id="5">
</br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="class1" data-id="1">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="class1" data-id="2">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="class1" data-id="3">30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="class1" data-id="4">40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="class1" data-id="5">50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
insert number
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Comment: i cannot use data-id since i cannot change the structure of html, i have only id and class .

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic, ID must be unique...You must have a parameter to relate elements..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to do your job effectively,

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("table td.class1");
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text'].class1");

Array.from(inputs).forEach(function(elm, i){
 elm.value = tds[i].textContent;
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uLv5zur2/)

Comment: Can u please explain me code? @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: Regarding the selector "table td.class1", is there any instance where a TD is not a descendant of a TABLE element?

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic simply we are iterating over an element collection and setting its value to elements in another one collection by using the index. Please have a look at the docs of `Array.prototype.forEach` as well. querySelectorAll will return an element collection not an array hence i have used `Array.from()` for converting the element collection to an array.